# Text detection Discord.py PRAW

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

```
@client.command(aliases=["h"])  # this is what the command will be in discord
async def letterh(ctx):
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit("theletterh").hot()
        post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
        for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
            submission = memes_submissions.__next__()
        if len(submission.selftext) == 0:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=submission.title,
                color=discord.Colour.purple()
            )
            embed.set_image(url=submission.url)
            embed.add_field(name="Author", value="u/" + submission.author.name, )
            embed.add_field(name="View Online", value=f"[Link]({submission.url})", )
            embed.add_field(name="Subreddit", value="r/TheLetterH", )
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title=submission.title,
                description=submission.selftext,
                color=discord.Colour.purple()
            )
            embed.add_field(name="Author", value="u/" + submission.author.name, )
            embed.add_field(name="View Online", value=f"[Link]({submission.url})", )
            embed.add_field(name="Subreddit", value="r/TheLetterH", )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is my code that posts text posts when detects it. But it doesn't. Rather than giving me and error, it me an image but not a text. The first one (`if len(submission.text == 0`) should post a text post if it detects it, and the other one (`else`) should post a normal image post if it doesn't have any text on it. But text don't work. Not a single error and I need you guys' help!

Comment: `if len(submission.selftext) == 0:` shouldn't work for image posts because they don't have `selftext`. Try instead `if not submission.is_self:`. Though I'm confused because you say that image posts do work and self posts don't.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!